# How to execute Datatable.Select() query for a column of type System.Color?

Tags: c#, datatable, system.data

I have a DataTable where one of the columns is of type `System.Color` and whenever I need to query some rows according by color value I can't find the right syntax for that.

I need a solution which looks something like:

```
DataRow[] _queried = dataTable.Select("ColorColumn = " + System.Color.Red);
```

I have tried as string and int and didn't find a working solution.

Comment: DataRow[] _queried = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where( x => x.Field<System.Color>("ColorColumn") == System.Color.Red).ToArray();

Comment: Do you mean `System.Drawing.Color`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DataTable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataTable_Select_System_String_) supports [column expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8) syntax, including `CONVERT` function. As it turns out, `CONVERT` works for columns of type `System.Drawing.Color` as well.

Something like this should work:

```
DataRow[] queried = table.Select("CONVERT(ColorColumn, System.String) = 'Color [Red]'");
```

or, if you want to pass `Color` as a variable:

```
var filterColor = Color.Red;
var queried = table.Select($"CONVERT(ColorColumn, System.String) = '{filterColor}'");
```

Runnable example:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Color", typeof(Color)));
        table.Rows.Add("First", Color.Red);
        table.Rows.Add("Second", Color.DarkRed);
        table.Rows.Add("Third", Color.Green);
        table.Rows.Add("Fourth", Color.Red);
        table.Rows.Add("Fifth", Color.Yellow);
        var filterColor = Color.Red;
        var queried = table.Select($"CONVERT(Color, System.String) = '{filterColor}'");
        //First, Fourth
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", queried.Select(r => r["Name"])));
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I have updated my code for a different purpose so can you please help me with this, Now I'm using a class which holds a color value and a index value and by which I'm forming a column

Class ColorWithIndex
{
     System.Drawing.Color Color;
      Int Index;
}

DataTable new = New DataTable();
new.Columns.Add("ColorColumn", typeOf(ColorWithIndex));

So Can I have the similar type of query as answered above

Comment: @GarudaPrasadK I assume yes. Have you tried it? What happened? Have you managed to make it work with `System.Color` (I didn't get any feedback, so I'm not sure) ?